# same error after updating to CLI 3.17.5 : Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

After updating to the latest Firebase CLI tool 3.17.5 from 3.17.4 I am having this error when I try to emulate the functions locally ?

how I can solve this problem?, I tried to update and refresh many times without success.

```
-functions inside the functions directory.
!  functions: Error from emulator. Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. Please ensure you have the latest firebase-functions SDK by running "npm i --save firebase-functions@latest" inside your functions folder.

Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.
    at init (D:\android-projects\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\config.js:55:15)
    at Object.config (D:\android-projects\firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\config.js:29:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\android-projects\firebase\functions\index.js:56:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
Shutting down...
```

Comment: after upgrading to 3.17.6 the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message isn't so much telling you about the CLI which you installed with `firebase-tools`.  It's specifically telling you about the `firebase-functions` dependency installed in your functions folder.  Please take its specific advice and install the latest firebase-functions module in your project.

Comment: I run all the update command no success

npm i --save firebase-functions@latest
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save

Comment: Then please file a bug with full reproduction steps (from the moment of firebase init).  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I can revert to the older version I tried to install it via npm install -g firebase-tools@^3.17.4, but now I m having new error   "!  functions: Failed to emulate helloWorld"

Comment: There is a version 3.17.6 now.  Maybe try that?  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.17.6